# How does man find git's subcommand manpages?

Tags: linux, git, macos, manpage

On my linux system, I can do "man git log" (note the space), and this will show me the manpage for git-log(1) (with a dash), as expected.

On my MacOSX machine, "man git log" only shows the manual page for git(1).

How does the linux man know that the two arguments "git" and "log" should be combined to find the "git-log" manpage? How would I get the same result in OSX?

Comment: what version of git do you have in your mac? and what version in your "linux system"?

Comment: git-log is not the appropriate command in osx, whereas git log is. It's a good question, my guess is git-log is a concatenation or something to let terminal know to look up both items, because man will execute the first argument and ignore the latter.

Comment: @KurzedMetal: 2.5.1 on OSX via MacPorts, 2.5.3 on Debian Sid

Comment: @nykc: actually, the `git` command is really just a dispatcher to a whole collection of subcommands  as executables usually located in some out-of-the-way directory. On Deb Sid, they're in /usr/lib/git-core/. On OSX via MacPorts they're in /opt/local/libexec/git-core/

You can run them from there directly! This setup is why their manpages list them with dashes.

Comment: @JohndeLargentaye I wasn't sure the reason but was interested in the answer. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a feature of the [particular implementation of `man`](http://man-db.nongnu.org/) used on many Linux systems.  Referring to the [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html) (for `man`), it is mentioned in the description of the `--no-subpages` option:

> **`--no-subpages`**
>
> By default, `man` will try to interpret *pairs* of manual page
>   names given on the command line as equivalent to a single
>   manual page name containing a *hyphen* or an *underscore*.  This
>   supports the common pattern of programs that implement a
>   number of subcommands, allowing them to provide manual pages
>   for each that can be accessed using similar syntax as would be
>   used to invoke the subcommands themselves.

Other implementations of `man` can do different things.  For instance (not well [documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/man.1.html), but *there* if you study it), a quick check for `man git status` on OSX *El Capitan* shows it tries to find a manual page for *status*.  However, `man git-status` gives a manual page.

Comment: Thanks! And I see it was added [mid-2009 by Colin Watson of Debian](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/man-db.git/commit/?id=7de45db026166ea55f9b7c240928ef0de0245a3f), which would explain why it was there for what felt like forever, but old versions of RedHat didn't have it.

Comment: Consequently, one may not enjoy the same behavior on Mac OS X, which does not have that particular man implementation, at least not out of the box, is that so?